# Is threadless a noticeable difference from threaded headset setups?

Tags: headset

I'm considering replacing my threaded aluminum forks, threaded headset, steel threaded stem and steel handlebars with threadless carbon forks, threadless headset and integrated carbon stem and handlebars; a large reduction in weight on my 700c road bike.

Aside from weight, what performance differences (if anything) should I notice or expect from the 1.0" threaded (guess) / 1 1/8" threadless headset change? Smoother turning? Or had the change in the industry been motivated on weight/production considerations?

One thing that I miss from the threaded setups is that the stem and forks can be engaged in a much stronger connection, such that it would take way more force to make them move independently. On my threadless setups, I can still force the handlebars to turn independent of the wheel, as the stem bolts strip out before they would provide as much clamping force as a threaded setup.

Comment: Are you sure your 1" headtube will accept a 1 1/8" headset and fork?

Comment: How much force are you applying to get the stem to move independently of the fork? I can't imagine that you  would encounter such a force except under crash conditions. Maybe you need a new stem bolt that won't strip out so easily.

Comment: I can hold the wheel and force the stem to slip around the steer tube; and cannot do this to threaded stems due to the expansion of the split shaft.

Comment: I'm basically interested in the ways in which a threadless is an 'upgrade', aside from weight reduction and allowing more modern components.

Comment: One of the big advantages of threaded is the huge selection in stem lengths and angles available. And the ability to switch the stem without unwrapping the bar tape.

Comment: Did you mean threadless? Both seem to have lots of lengths and angles, and changing stems without unwrapping is a feature of the stem (the ones that bolt a plate on each side), all of this independent of the headset choice.

Comment: I have a feeling you've got your threadless system setup wrong if you're able to force the stem to spin around.

Comment: On my last build, I tried to make it so I couldn't spin the stem with the wheel held, and pulled the threads out of the aluminum stem before it would tighten enough. This is a carbon fiber integrated stem and handlebar with aluminum nutserts, and it is tightened until the carbon fiber started crackling some. If I hold the wheel, I can still budge the handlebars.

Comment: I've had various bikes with threadless headsets for 18+ years and I've never had an issue with movement between fork and stem.  I assume you've already tried the gritty carbon assembly goo ?  I suspect your stem/handlebar combo may be to blame.  Your experience is certainly not typical of threadless headsets and stems.

Comment: I have not tried gritty carbon assembly goo, but I will now. I don't really see it as a huge problem; I don't typically hold the wheel and reef on the handlebars, but I do think it's worth noting that a casual tighten of a threaded stem can handle more twisting force than as much tightening as I can get out of aluminum and carbon fiber threadless stems.

Comment: Carbon fiber started crackling some? With CF you're always supposed to use the torque wrench. Maybe you damaged the CF by overtightening.

Comment: Maybe, but I cannot tighten it anymore; and I have pulled the threads out of aluminum stems before trying to tighten them enough. Try it on your bike: trap the front wheel between your feet and reef on the bars; I suspect you can get it to budge, too.

Comment: Why on earth would you do that? If you feel the need to "reef" on your bike, buy a BSO from Walmart till you get it out of your system.

Comment: Because I feel like it. Bottom line is, a marginally tightened quill stem can resist said force, and Aluminum/Carbon Fiber threadless stems cannot. I will try again with the assembly goo, but in this regard I think threaded setups are stronger.

Comment: If a quill stem isn't overtightened, it will also allow your handlebars to rotate relative to your stem in a crash situation. I suspect the difference is less quill vs threadless and more steel vs carbon. http://sheldonbrown.com/handsup.html "If a bicycle has an older quill stem with a conical expander, it is normal to be able to turn the handlebars with moderately strong hand force, when standing in front of the bicycle and holding the front wheel between the legs. Turning the handlebars will be more difficult if the stem has a wedge."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically, you can adjust the height of a threadless headset moving around the position of the spacers. The problem is that most threadless headsets come with very little room (or none at all) to adjust the stem up and down.  The leaves the only way to adjust the height is by purchasing a new stem, which doesn't give you the option of switching mid ride.

Also worth pointing out that while the connection on a threaded headset may be stronger, the threadless setup is strong enough for most riding conditions. Threadless headsets are used on all kinds of bikes, from road, to mountain, and even downhill.  If it didn't provide a strong enough connection, you wouldn't have manufacturers risking lawsuits with something that is known to be inferior.

Also, a threaded headset has a single point of failure that's difficult to inspect.  If you are using the style of quill with an expander (see below) there is a decent chance that over time the stem will break from the pressure of the expansion (I know someone it happened to, twice).  With a wedge style, this not a possibility, but you still have a single point of failure if wedge nut or bolt brakes, or even if it loosens over time. There's always 2 bolts on threadless, so no single point of failure, and it's easier to inspect what's going on to see early signs of wear.

The biggest problem I know of with threaded headsets though is that the stem has a tendency to rust to the steerer, and is sometimes practically impossible to remove. This is preventable with regular maintenance, but there's a lot of bikes out there that don't get as much maintenance as they need, and most non-enthusiasts would probably never think of checking the quill for rust and regreasing a couple times a year.  Most people would probably be afraid to disassemble the headset to ensure things aren't starting to rust, and many people don't like going to the bike shop for things until something actually isn't working because of high prices.

[image: Quill Stem Styles]

Answer (score 4):

Threadless forks aren't a significant upgrade in any way other than weight and simplicity of setup/maintenance.

Depending on exactly what the steerer tube is made of and how much is exposed above the headset, they can be stiffer when pulling on the bars in a sprint, but for the other 99.9% of the time there is no difference.

Having said that, I'd would never go back. The advantages in weight and maintenance are well worth it.

P.S. You should really double check your measurements, a 1.125 inch threaded headset is a relatively rare item. They were made, but only for a few years and as far as I know only on mountain bikes and tandems. It would be very rare to find one on a road bike of any vintage.

Comment: I didn't measure here. The head tube is the right diameter to accept a 1.25" threadless headset. It currently has a threaded setup. Does that make it a 1.0" threaded headset then?

Comment: The 1.125 is the dimension of the steerer tube. So the head tube would need to have an interior dimension greater than that. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headset_(bicycle_part) for exact dimensions of the headtube.

Comment: I'll measure it when I get home; suffice it to say I know it will accept a 1.25" threadless headset/fork if I pressed one in.

Comment: Head tube O.D. is 37.4mm, I can't find a good place to measure the steerer tube without removing the stem. It's the 'right size' to press in a standard 1 1/8" threadless headset.

Comment: So - why did the industry make the switch? Is it production / costs? Or the larger diameter steerer tube the same head tube accommodate? So far, threaded setups have the advantage of height adjustment without cutting, and a stronger connection, disadvantage of weight. Anything else?